# Why are FIFO One-quarter full, Half-full, three-quarter full interrupts provided in a UART RX FIFO? What are their use cases?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, uart, fifo, isr

I am implementing a protocol decoder which receives bytes through UART of a microcontroller. The ISR takes bytes from the UART peripheral and puts it in a ring buffer. The main loop reads from the ring buffer and runs a state machine to decode it.

The UART internally has a 32-byte receive FIFO, and provides interrupts when this FIFO is quarter-full, half-full, three-quarter full and completely full. How should i determine which of these interrupts should trigger my ISR? What is the tradeoff involved?

Note - The protocol involves packets of 32-byte (fixed length), send every 10ms.

Comment: This questions should be moved to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question is about how software should handle this case. I think this question can be answered here in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Swanand It is on-topic on either site.

Comment: @SreekeshSreelal When posting questions like this on SO, make sure to include the embedded tag. That will draw attention to your question from the right kind of people. I have updated the tags.

Comment: Thanks @Swanand for the correct guidelines!

Comment: Thanks @Lundin for adding the embedded tag!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on a lot of things, most of all the maximum baudrate supported, and how much time your application needs for executing other tasks.

Traditional ring buffers work on byte-per-byte interrupt basis. But it is of course always nice to reduce the number of interrupts. It probably doesn't matter much how often you let it trigger.

It is much more important to implement a double-buffer scheme. You should of course *not* start to run a state machine decoding straight from a single ring buffer. That will turn into a race condition nightmare.

Your main program should hit the semaphore/disable the UART interrupt, then copy the whole buffer, then allow interrupt. Ideally buffer copy is done by changing a pointer, rather than doing a hard copy. The code doing this needs to be benchmarked to perform faster than 1/baudrate * 10 seconds. Where 10 is: 1 start, 8 data, 1 stop, assuming UART is 8-N-1.

If available, use DMA over software ring buffers.

Comment: Can you explain why a double buffer(ping-pong buffer) is needed in this situation? The ISR may be writing using (say) the head pointer, and main program is reading using the tail pointer. Assume that the ISR drops bytes if at all it finds the ring buffer buffer is full. Why should I use double buffer as the ISR is writing to one end of the buffer and main program is reading from the other end. Can you explain where is the race condition? I guess iam missing this.

Comment: @SreekeshSreelal The race condition is between any ISR sharing variables with calling code, ring buffers don't solve that unless designed to be ISR-safe. There will always be situations when the same variable is accessed by the caller and the ISR at the same time. And if you access the ring buffer from the caller for longer time than 1 byte on the UART, you can't disable the ISR as the safety measure or you risk UART overrun. Having a large hardware buffer helps a lot there, since it buys time. You need some means of fast copy of all the data, which a double buffer offers.

Comment: Assume that ring buffer is implemented using an array, and integer variables are used as head and tail pointers. If i can make sure that the head and tail counter of ring buffer are atomic types, then I guess the ring buffer will be interrupt safe (Correct me if this is wrong). After making the head and tail pointers atomic, there is no need to disable interrupts. Why doesnt this solve the problem?

Comment: @SreekeshSreelal Yes, if all shared variables are atomic then it is probably fine. Not many embedded compilers support `_Atomic` though. You still need to protect the actual data access though, no way around it. The caller will always empty the ring buffer and the ISR fill it up. There will be plenty of cases where they try to access the same data, when `tail==head`.

Comment: I can make the shared variables atomic by using the native size of the integer on the processor (for example, uint8_t on a 8-bit processor). If so, i need not disable interrupts right? Why do i need to again protect the actual data in the buffer? The ISR and main loop uses opposite ends of the buffer, and we are doing checks to make sure that ISR drops bytes when the buffer is full and main loop never processes data when buffer is found empty. So when tail==head , the main never tries to process the data. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @SreekeshSreelal "I can make the shared variables atomic by using the native size of the integer on the processor"  No, you can't, unless you write everything in assembler. Please read this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188268/discussion-between-sreekesh-sreelal-and-lundin).

Answer (score 1):

Given a packet based protocol and a UART that interrupts when more than one byte has been received, consider what should happen if the final byte of a packet is received but that final byte isn't enough to fill the FIFO past the threshold and trigger an interrupt.  Is your application simply not going to receive that incomplete packet until some subsequent packet is received and the FIFO finally fills enough?  What if the other end is waiting for a response and never sends another packet?  Or is your application supposed to poll the UART to check for lingering bytes remaining in the UART FIFO?  That seems overly complicated to both use an interrupt and poll for received bytes.

With the packet-based protocols I have implemented, the UART driver does not rely on the UART FIFO and configures the UART to interrupt when a single byte is available.  This way the driver gets notified for every byte and there is no chance for the final byte of a packet to be left lingering in the UART's FIFO.

The UART's FIFO can be convenient for streaming protocols (such as audio or video data).  When the driver is receiving a stream of data then there will always be incoming data to keep filling the FIFO.  The driver can rely on the UART's FIFO to buffer some data.  The driver can be more efficient by processing multiple bytes per interrupt and reducing the interrupt rate.

You might consider using the UART FIFO since your packets are a fixed length.  But consider how the driver would recover if a single byte is dropped due to noise or whatever.  I think it's still best to not rely on the FIFO for packet-based protocols regardless of whether the packets are fixed length.